# Jackson: Store JSON-Node-Source within deserialized Object

Tags: java, jackson

In Java (using Spring Boot, if of any help) given any JSON-Source and an accoring nested model structure - is it possible to store the JSON-Source-String of an accoring node within the deserialized object (preferably without the use of a custom deserializer)?

Example:

```
{
      "myProp" : "myValue"
}
```

Should deserialize to object:

```
private String myProp; //Initialized with "myValue"
private String jsonSource; //Initialized with whole Json-Node-Source-String (in this case "{"myProp":"myValue"}")
```

Comment: what do you mean by jsonsource?

Comment: I mean the original json-string of the node the object-instance was deserialized from

Comment: That's not possible by default.